# How can I add page numbers to each page's footer with python-docx?

Tags: python, python-2.7, docx, python-docx

I think this question is pretty self explanatory. From what I've read of the python-docx documentation, it seems that the header and footer must be exactly the same on every page, which of course makes adding page numbers difficult. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Adding headers and footers is a feature not yet implemented.

However...

- If it is an existing document you want to add headers and footers to you can call a VBA-macro. I recently posted a way to do that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44767400/7386332)
- If it is a new document then you can indeed go on and create a template document first and then open it up and continue editing as described by scanny.

Comment: There ought to be a way to do this entirely within `python-docx` API, as it refers to this use case in its docs but doesn't demonstrate how. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/header.html?highlight=page%20number

Comment: Well, now there is. Haven’t looken into it though.

Comment: besides python-docx documentation itself, can you find any place on SO or elsewhere that demonstrates how to insert page numbers into a header or footer, without using VBA macro or other Win32 specific libraries?

Comment: if not, I'll ask it as a new question, as this has not been provided. Or I'll bounty this one

Comment: I need this to work on a linux server, without windows binaries present, and pure python, not VBA

Comment: Better open a new q

Answer (score 0):

A Word document produced by `python-docx` will preserve any headers and footers present in the "template" document. So the way to get those is to create a "starting" document that has the headers and footers you're after.

A header or footer can contain a *page number field*, which is automatically updated with the current page number at display and/or print time. This is added using the Insert > Field > Page Number menu option in Word. Different Word versions do this slightly differently, but this should get you close enough to find it on your version. Otherwise a search on "Insert page number Word 2013" with your version will find you many resources.