# How to fetch Total No of pages count in Python-docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx, page-numbering

I am learning Python-docx and I am using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62534711/16596765) to add page number as given on stackoverflow by @Utkarsh Dalal

```
def create_element(name):
    return OxmlElement(name)


def create_attribute(element, name, value):
    element.set(nsqn(name), value)


def add_page_number(paragraph):
    paragraph.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER

    page_run = paragraph.add_run()
    t1 = create_element('w:t')
    create_attribute(t1, 'xml:space', 'preserve')
    t1.text = 'Page '
    page_run._r.append(t1)

    page_num_run = paragraph.add_run()

    fldChar1 = create_element('w:fldChar')
    create_attribute(fldChar1, 'w:fldCharType', 'begin')

    instrText = create_element('w:instrText')
    create_attribute(instrText, 'xml:space', 'preserve')
    instrText.text = "PAGE"

    fldChar2 = create_element('w:fldChar')
    create_attribute(fldChar2, 'w:fldCharType', 'end')

    page_num_run._r.append(fldChar1)
    page_num_run._r.append(instrText)
    page_num_run._r.append(fldChar2)

    of_run = paragraph.add_run()
    t2 = create_element('w:t')
    create_attribute(t2, 'xml:space', 'preserve')
    t2.text = ' of '
    of_run._r.append(t2)

    fldChar3 = create_element('w:fldChar')
    create_attribute(fldChar3, 'w:fldCharType', 'begin')

    instrText2 = create_element('w:instrText')
    create_attribute(instrText2, 'xml:space', 'preserve')
    instrText2.text = "NUMPAGES"

    fldChar4 = create_element('w:fldChar')
    create_attribute(fldChar4, 'w:fldCharType', 'end')

    num_pages_run = paragraph.add_run()
    num_pages_run._r.append(fldChar3)
    num_pages_run._r.append(instrText2)
    num_pages_run._r.append(fldChar4)

    for pg in num_pages_run.element:
        print(pg.text)


doc = Document()
add_page_number(doc.sections[0].footer.paragraphs[0])
doc.save("your_doc.docx")
```

I receive the Page number in format of Page x of y.
But when I try to access the value of 'y' for total number of pages, I could not do it. I have tried to access it getting the text attribute of num_pages_run  as pg.text. But all I get is NUMPAGES as output instead of number of pages.

I am looking for this feature because I would like to do some actions whenever a new page is added to the document.

Is there a way to get total pages from python-docx or any other alternative?

Comment: A `.docx` file contains no concept of a "page". The content of the document is divided into pages by the renderer, maybe the Word application or Google Docs or whatever, based on the printer capabilities and available fonts. So there is no general-case method to discover the number of "pages" in a document file.